# Bash: mv deletes files because it exists despite renaming hasn't finished

Tags: bash, mv

It's on Mac OS 10.11.

There may happen file deletions when renaming files in a batch.
Example: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt should be renamed to 3.txt, 2.txt, 1.txt
With the regular way, 1.txt becomes 3.txt (deleting the original 3.txt), 2.txt 2.txt, and then 3.txt (the original 1.txt) becomes 1.txt again. Only 1.txt and 2.txt stay.

To prohibit this, in a first step, I suffix all input names with a random name; in the second step, I change the suffixed names to the their final output names. Full example - please save to a sh file and test for yourself:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -u -x

echo 1 > 1.txt
echo 2 > 2.txt
echo 3 > 3.txt

InputFiles=(1.txt 2.txt 3.txt)
OutputFiles=(3.txt 2.txt 1.txt)

suffix="_rename_cnowjfo_"
i=0
count=3
while (( i < count )); do
    mv "${InputFiles[i]}" "${InputFiles[i]}$suffix"
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
#sleep 3
i=0
while (( i < count )); do
    mv -n "${InputFiles[i]}$suffix" "${OutputFiles[i]}"
    echo $?
    #sleep 0.5
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Doing this two times ({1..3}.txt - {3..1}.txt and {1..3}.txt - {3..1}.txt again) to reset the original names will work fine the first time, but the second time, 1.txt is **deleted** due to unknown reasons.

Second execution with set -v:

```
+ ((  i < count  ))
+ mv 1.txt 1.txt_rename_cnowjfo_
+ i=1
+ ((  i < count  ))
+ mv 2.txt 2.txt_rename_cnowjfo_
+ i=2
+ ((  i < count  ))
+ mv 3.txt 3.txt_rename_cnowjfo_
+ i=3
+ ((  i < count  ))
+ i=0
+ ((  i < count  ))
+ mv -n 1.txt_rename_cnowjfo_ 3.txt
+ echo 0
0
+ i=1
+ ((  i < count  ))
+ mv -n 2.txt_rename_cnowjfo_ 2.txt
+ echo 0
0
+ i=2
+ ((  i < count  ))
+ mv -n 3.txt_rename_cnowjfo_ 1.txt
+ echo 0
0
+ i=3
+ ((  i < count  ))
```

Now I uncomment the sleep command above, and everything seems to work as expected. It seems that without the sleep command, mv may not have finished its job despite exiting.

The same happens if I manually execute all 6 commands:

```
mv 1.txt 1.txt_rename_cnowjfo_; mv 2.txt 2.txt_rename_cnowjfo_; mv 3.txt 3.txt_rename_cnowjfo_; mv 1.txt_rename_cnowjfo_ 3.txt; mv 2.txt_rename_cnowjfo_ 2.txt; mv 3.txt_rename_cnowjfo_ 1.txt
```

The same happens on all file systems I tested: MAC OS extended, ExFAT and FAT16.

**How can mv exit without having fully done the job?**

Comment: What file system do the files reside on?

Comment: `mv` is atomic and synchronous, it shouldn't exit until it has fully done the job.

Comment: Despite `mv` being atomic why using weird suffixes when you can make use of `tempfile` command easily?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the transcript above. If the first rename didn't finish, you would get an error when you tried to rename the resulting file.

Comment: @choroba Mac OS Extended (Journaled, encrypted)

Comment: @DevilaN Because this would need a separate library. In my shell there is no `tempfile` command.

Comment: @Barmar Correct, `ls .` proves that all files have been renamed, but 1.txt is deleted anyway.

Comment: You may not have a `tempfile` command, but you almost certainly have `mktemp`.

Comment: ...and `mv` **doesn't** exit unless the filesystem told it the rename syscall was complete. If your filesystem is lying to you, we can't debug that without knowing much more about what operating system you're on, how the relevant partitions are formatted, which if any network filesystems are in the way, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is really strange, I didn't ever experience this until now. See my update about different FS's

Comment: Hmm. Apple's basic filesystem is pretty darned stable -- if it were this far from POSIX compliance, that would be widespread knowledge (and lots of very basic UNIX software wouldn't work at all).

Comment: BTW, `mv -n` ("noclobber") is your friend, if you want the operation to fail rather than overwrite a preexisting destination.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Same result with `-n` option. (I already checked if the target name exists, and it officially doesn't.) I checked my SSD ("SanDisk SDSSDA480G"), too, and everything is in order. - As soon as I append half a second `sleep` after each `mv`, it works as expected.

Comment: Wait, `mv -n` **deletes the destination file**, it doesn't fail? That's directly contrary to documentation (and frankly, rather hard to believe).

Comment: Is your filesystem mounted with case sensitivity enabled?

Comment: ...at this point, I would be inclined to suggest using dtrace to get a log of all the syscalls impacting your files. That way anything else going on -- a separate copy of your script running at the same time, for example -- will be made obvious.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Of course it doesn't (here: it shouldn't) because the target file does not exist (because of my temporary names). I have updated the example so you can test for yourself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's not case sensitive, but this shouldn't be of any concern for my example. Enough disk space and is the first volume.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple due to my fault - not having checked the final results with the shell but instead with the Finder app. Finder seems to be overwhelmed by the fast changes, and *only after killing and restarting* shows all 3 files. `ls` instantly shows that all 3 files have been correctly renamed.

**Never rely on a GUI to get a reliable view on your files!**

Comment: That's strange. I just renamed a file on my desktop from a terminal, and I saw the desktop change the moment I pressed Return. I'm using High Sierra.

Comment: MacOS has an API that allows applications to subscribe to notifications about file and directory changes (Spotlight updates its indexes, Time Machine adds the directory to the upcoming backup). I'd expect Finder to use this to detect renames immediately.

Comment: @Barmar Just test my script above for yourself and give me a feedback.

Comment: I tried it, and during some of the runs I could briefly see the `_rename_cnowjfo_` files, but they changed to the filenames without the suffixes in less than a second.

Comment: It never lasted long enough for me to think that the script hadn't worked.